# Wrong date in jdtojewish function in php

Tags: php, date, hebrew, julian-date

I want to convert the Gregorian calendar to the Hebrew date, so I use this code:

```
    $jd = gregoriantojd(2, 25, 2020);
    echo jdtojewish($jd); // the reuslt is: 5/30/5780
```

and then, when I add one day to the date, the month jumps up two months instead of one month,

```
    $jd = gregoriantojd(2, 26, 2020);
    echo jdtojewish($jd); // the result is: 7/1/5780
```

The right output should be *6*/1/5780. how can I get the right Hebrew date ?

Comment: How you can say `7/1/5780` is not right?

Comment: Welcome to working with dates

Answer (score 0):

Here is the explanation in 9 year old bug report https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61185
The problem is that on non-leap years PHP function jdtojewish just skips 6th month